# Add an extra fee to paypal standard

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1.9, payment-methods, billing, paypal-standard

[image]

i am add some extra fee in cart on base of some special conditions.It's work fine all all place in magento but now i think about add this fee to paypal standard.I am successful but it works only if Transfer Cart Line Items = No.

I want to work it where Transfer Cart Line Items = yes in paypal option.

Now i want one row on paypal bill with fee lable & value.

[image: Paypal standard bill with Transfer Cart Line Items SET yes]

It can come with tax and item total or items and shipping both option are good for me.
Can any body help me?

Comment: Check with paypal developer community..

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to add extra lines in PayPal Standard cart using the `paypal_prepare_line_items` event.

In your module's config.xml:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <events>
            <paypal_prepare_line_items>
                <observers>
                    <paypal_prepare_line_items>
                        <class>your_module/observer</class>
                        <method>updatePaypalTotal</method>
                    </paypal_prepare_line_items>
                </observers>
            </paypal_prepare_line_items>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

In your observer:

```
class Your_Module_Model_Observer
{
    public function updatePaypalTotal(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $feeAmount = <calculated somewhere...>

        /* @var $cart Mage_Paypal_Model_Cart */
        $cart = $observer->getEvent()->getPaypalCart();

        $cart->addItem('Fee label', 1, $feeAmount, 'fee');

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: PayPal gateway has rejected request. The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts (#10413: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details).